# The word odd meaning

Tags: word-meaning

What does the word odd mean in the following sentence?

> Add these 'superfoods' to your daily diet, and you will increase your
>   odds of maintaining a healthy brain for the rest of your life.

[Source](http://www.webmd.com/diet/eat-smart-healthier-brain)

Comment: [See dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odds) Sorry, but have to VTC for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, *odds* means a chance or probability.